# How to print a string with '\n' in the middle in two lines?

Tags: c, printf

I have a problem. I need to create a program in C that takes a string as a parameter and print it. The problem is: if I put `\n` or `\t` in the middle, my program prints it as `n` or `t`. But I need to print them as a new line or tabulation. Program must understand `\n` and `\t`. How can I do it?

Expected result:

```sh
$> ./my_program aaa\nbbb
aaa
bbb
$>
```

My (incorrect) result:

```sh
$> ./my_program aaa\nbbb
aaanbbb
$>
```

That's my code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    int i = 0;
    //printf("%s", argv[1]); - that doesn't works also :(
    while (argv[1][i] != '\0') {
        printf("%c", argv[1][i]);
        i++;
    }
    return (0); 
}
```

I tried use `printf` and `write` functions. I tried to print it as a string or by characters...

Comment: Either pass an escaped `'\n'` in the argument or re-write code to look for pairs like of characters like \ and n and print a `'\n'`.

Comment: There are two ways: The first is to have the shell pass an actual newline or tab character into the argument; The second way is to make sure that the shell doesn't strip the backslash, and then your code must parse the string itself to check if there's a backslash and then get the next character (if there is any) and check if it's a `'n'` or a `'t'`.

Comment: It's not a deal for your program but shell you use to run it. `./my_program aaa$'\n'bbb`

Answer (score 7):

Once you have a string with a newline embedded in it, printing it out on two lines is utterly trivial--almost anything that can print out a string will do exactly that.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 
    char const *s = "aaa\nbbb";
    printf("%s", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
aaa
bbb
```

So, the problem you face is not with printing out the string, and not really even related to C itself at all. Your real question comes down to: "how do you pass a command line parameter with an embedded newline?" Fortunately, there is a pretty easy way to do that (at least with bash or zsh). Let's start with a simple program to print out the first command line argument:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <string>\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("%s", argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

From there, it's all about how we invoke the program:

```
./a.out aaa$'\n'bbb
```

Result:

```
aaa
bbb
```

The "trick" here is the `$'\n'`, which tells the shell to "expand" the `\n` so the invoked program will see it as a newline.

Comment: Wow! 40 years of shell commands on various unices and I did not know about this `$'\n'` trick :)

Comment: @chqrlie:  I wouldn't feel too badly--few people seem to know about it, and I'm not sure it's been around for 40 years yet anyway...

Answer (score 4):

You program outputs the command line argument one character at a time: using `%s` achieves the same result:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {   
    if (argc > 1)
        printf("%s", argv[1]);
    return 0; 
}
```

The problem comes from the way the command shell handles the `\` character.  Your shell does not interpret `\n` as a newline in the command line argument, it interprets it as an escape for quotes and the `\` itself.

You can pass a newline inside a command line argument by quoting the argument this way:

```sh
$> ./my_program 'aaa
bbb'
aaa
bbb
$>
```

Alternately, you can pass the `\` to the program by writing `./my_program aaa\\nbbb` or `./my_program 'aaa\nbbb'` and modify the program to interpret escape sequences explicitly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int print_escaped_string(const char *s) {
    int n = 0;
    while (*s != '\0') {
        unsigned char uc = *s++;
        if (uc == '\\') {
            switch (*s) {
              case '\\':             s++; break;
              case 'n': uc = '\n';   s++; break;
              case 't': uc = '\t';   s++; break;
              case 'e': uc = '\033'; s++; break;
            }
        }
        putchar(uc);
        n++;
    }
    return n;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {   
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        print_escaped_string(argv[i]);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To print 2 characters `\` `n` or print 2 characters `\` `t` as a line-feed and tab, process the string looking for a `\` that begins an *escape sequence*.

C defines 4 escape sequences.

- simple-escape-sequence
- octal-escape-sequence
- hexadecimal-escape-sequence
- universal-character-name

Looking at just the *simple-escape-sequences*, C defines:
\’ \" \? \\ \a \b \f \n \r \t \v

So in addition to the \n \t, code could look for all of them

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc > 1) {
    const char *s = argv[1];
    while (*s != '\0') {
      if (*s == '\\') {
        s++;
        const char c[] = {'\"', '\'', '?', '\\', 'a', 'b', 'f', 'n', 'r', 't', 'v', 0};
        const char e[] = {'\"', '\'', '?', '\\', '\a', '\b', '\f', '\n', '\r', '\t', '\v', 0};
        const char *find = strchr(c, *s);
        if (find && *find) {
          putchar(e[find - c]);
        } else {
          fprintf(stderr, "Invalid escape sequence found \\%3o\n", (unsigned char) *s);
          break;
          // or perhaps look for the other 3 types of escape sequences...
        }
      } else {
        putchar(*s);
      }
      s++;
    }
  }
}
```